# search in json values from mysql tables

Tags: mysql, json

I have some data like :

```
id  name  ccode  json
1   john   231   {"age": 12,"score": 90}
2   danny   231   {"age": 22,"score": 87}
3   danniel   231   {"age": 18,"score": 48}
4   sara   431   {"age": 16,"score": 67}
```

now, i want get all fields of all users that they ages are between 15 to 24 and they ccode is 231.

result must be something like :

```
2   danny   231   {"age": 22,"score": 87}
3   danniel   231   {"age": 18,"score": 48}
```

Comment: Found something here: http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/mysql-5-7-sql-functions-for-json-udf/

Comment: Why do you store it as a json string inside your db, why not use separate columns for age and score? I'm just curious on why you took this approach.

Comment: If you want to search the json (from within MySQL), you should decode it and store it in a normalised fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the  following query ,

```
select id,name,ccode,json, CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(json, ',', 1)  FROM 8)  AS UNSIGNED) as val 
from events 
where ccode=231  having val>15 and val<24;
```